# Retrieve texfield value and post to query

Tags: php, oracle

So, I have the following code like this:

```
<input type="text" name="months">
<input class="button" type="submit" onclick="message()" value="Submit"/>

<?   
$monthss=$_POST['months'];
echo $monthss;

$q = "Select to_char(tgl_val,'MM-YYYY') as tglmonth where bt_number=".$bt_number." and to_char(tgl_val,'MM-YYYY')=".$monthss." order by tglmonth asc";
$s2=OCIParse($c_slave,$q);
//OCIBindByName($s2,":bind1",$ordernumber);
OCIExecute($s2,OCI_DEFAULT);

    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "MONTH";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "AMOUNT";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "DISCOUNT_AMOUNT";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "SERVICES";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "TAX";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "TOTAL_AMOUNT";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "PRINT";
    echo "</td></tr>";


while (OCIFetch($s2))
{
    $V_TGLMONTH         = oci_result($s2,'TGLMONTH');
    $V_AMOUNT             = oci_result($s2,'AMOUNT');
    $V_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT    = oci_result($s2,'DISCOUNT_AMOUNT');
    $V_SERVICES           = oci_result($s2,'SERVICES');
    $V_TAX                = oci_result($s2,'TAX');
    $V_TOTAL_AMOUNT       = oci_result($s2,'TOTAL_AMOUNT');

    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "<a href=\"tgl.php?tmt=".substr($V_TGLMONTH,0,2)."&tmm=".substr($V_TGLMONTH,3,4)."\">";
    echo $V_TGLMONTH;
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_AMOUNT;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_SERVICES;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_TAX;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $V_TOTAL_AMOUNT;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "PRINT";
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

The point is I have textfield and button. after I fill the texfield with **mm-yyyy** and click the button, the result should show all of the record in those month. but when I fill the textfield with **01-2014** and click the button nothings happen. Can you guys help me with this?

Comment: Beware of the SQL injections in your code, e.g. when using the `$monthss`-variable.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

Here's my final html code:

```
<form name="myForm" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<input type="text" name="months" placeholder="mm-yyyy">
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

And it's the PHP code:

```
<?
$months=$_POST['months']; 
echo "<br><strong>Selected Month: </strong>" .$months;
echo "<br><br>";

$q = "Select AMOUNT, SERVICES, BILL_NO, ORDER_NUMBER, TOTAL_AMOUNT, to_char(PAY_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') as PAY_DATE from payment_final where bt_number=".$bt_number." and to_char(tgl_val,'MM-YYYY')='".$months."' order by bill_no";
?>
```